# Label appears in IE but not Chrome?

Tags: html, vb.net, google-chrome

I'm working on a website that displays a lot of products in little *cards* so they all appear in the same format. However, some of the products are displaying in Chrome without their prices, I've checked in other browsers and the issue is only in Chrome.

This is taken from Internet Explorer and shows what the product cards should look like.

[image]

And this is the same product in Chrome:

[image]

Very helpfully displaying a cost of not there.

**HTML** - The label in question is lblProductPrice

```
<div class="index-row">
    <asp:DataList runat="server" ID="dlFeaturedProducts" RepeatColumns="5" RepeatDirection="horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow" >
        <itemstyle VerticalAlign="top" />
        <itemtemplate>
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlProduct" runat="server" defaultbutton="btnBuy">
                <div class="gallery-product">
                    <div class="gallery-product-image">
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="hlProductImage"  runat="server"><img id="imgProduct" runat="server" /></asp:HyperLink>
                    </div>

                    <div class="gallery-product-details">
                    <div class="gallery-product-freight">
                            <span runat="server" id="divFreeFreight" visible="false"><img src="images/free-delivery.png" alt="Free Shipping On This Item" title="Free Shipping On This Item" /></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="gallery-product-title">
                            <asp:HyperLink ID="hlProductTitle" runat="server"></asp:HyperLink></strong><asp:Label ID="lblProductID" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="gallery-product-price">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblProductPrice" runat="server"></asp:Label> <span class="gallery-product-price-gst">Incl GST</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="gallery-product-usually">
                            <span id="pnlUsually" runat="server"><asp:Label ID="lblWas" runat="server"></asp:Label><asp:Label ID="lblListPrice" runat="server"></asp:Label></span>&nbsp;
                        </div>

                          <div class="gallery-product-blurb">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblWebBlurb" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input name="hidden" type="hidden" id="UniqueCode" value="" runat="server" />
                    <div class="gallery-buy-bg">
                        <div class="gallery-buy">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity" Text="1" Width="25" MaxLength="4" runat="server" CssClass="textbox" style="text-align:center"></asp:TextBox><br />(quantity)
                        </div>
                        <div class="gallery-buy-button">
                            <div class="grey-button">
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnBuy" runat="server" title="Add to Cart" Text="Add to Cart" CommandName="Add" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </asp:Panel>
        </itemtemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
</div>
```

**VB.Net** - I've tried setting the value for lblProductPrice before, after and in the if/else statement, and it makes no difference to either browser.

```
'Show Product Savings even if discount level on login
            If dr("SELLPRICE9") > 0 And dr("pListPrice") = 0 Then
                If ((dr("SELLPRICE9")) - dr(c.GetPriceLevel())) > ((dr("SELLPRICE1")) - dr(c.GetPriceLevel())) Then
                    'lblProductPrice.Text = "$" + FormatNumber(dr(c.GetPriceLevel()), 2)
                    'lblProductPrice.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Black
                    lblListPrice.Font.Strikeout = True
                    lblWas.Text = "RRP "
                    lblWas.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
                    lblListPrice.Text = "$" + FormatNumber(dr("SELLPRICE9"), 2)
                    lblListPrice.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
                Else
                    lblWas.Text = ""
                    'lblProductPrice.Text = "$" + FormatNumber(dr(c.GetPriceLevel()), 2)
                    'lblProductPrice.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Black
                    lblListPrice.Text = ""
                End If

            Else
                If (dr("SELLPRICE1")) > (dr("pListPrice")) Then
                    'lblProductPrice.Text = "$" + FormatNumber(dr(c.GetPriceLevel()), 2)
                Else
                    'lblProductPrice.Text = "$" + FormatNumber(dr(c.GetPriceLevel()), 2)
                    lblWas.Text = "Save $"
                    lblListPrice.Font.Strikeout = False
                    lblListPrice.Text = FormatNumber((dr("pListPrice") - dr(c.GetPriceLevel())), 2)
                    If (dr("pListPrice") - dr(c.GetPriceLevel())) = 0 Then
                        lblListPrice.Visible = False
                        lblWas.Visible = False
                    End If
                End If
                'If lblListPrice.Text <= 0 Then
                '    Dim pnlUsually As HtmlContainerControl = CType(e.Item.FindControl("pnlUsually"), HtmlContainerControl)
                '    pnlUsually.Visible = False
                'End If
            End If
            lblProductPrice.Text = "$" + FormatNumber(dr("SELLPRICE1"), 2)
        End If
```

**Client HTML - IE**

```
<span valign="top">
            <div id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_pnlProduct_15" onkeypress="javascript:return WebForm_FireDefaultButton(event, &#39;ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_btnBuy_15&#39;)">

                <div class="gallery-product">
                    <div class="gallery-product-image">
                        <a id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_hlProductImage_15" title="2m HDMI V1.4 Cable" href="Computers/Cables-(Ready-Made)/DVI-HDMI-Cables/Product-Specification-CB30202.aspx"><img src="http://www.globalpc.co.nz/prodimages/CB30201.jpg.axd?maxwidth=165&maxheight=100" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_imgProduct_15" alt="2m HDMI V1.4 Cable" border="0" /></a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="gallery-product-details">
                    <div class="gallery-product-freight">

                        </div>
                        <div class="gallery-product-title">
                            <a id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_hlProductTitle_15" href="Computers/Cables-(Ready-Made)/DVI-HDMI-Cables/Product-Specification-CB30202.aspx">2m HDMI V1.4 Cable</a></strong>
                        </div>
                        <div class="gallery-product-price">
                            <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_lblProductPrice_15">$19.00</span> <span class="gallery-product-price-gst">Incl GST</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="gallery-product-usually">
                            <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_pnlUsually_15"><span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_lblWas_15"></span><span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_lblListPrice_15"></span></span>&nbsp;
                        </div>

                          <div class="gallery-product-blurb">
                            <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_lblWebBlurb_15"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dlFeaturedProducts$ctl15$UniqueCode" type="hidden" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_UniqueCode_15" value="b2cb5ee5-97d4-44a7-99f7-ffa66790ae0c" />
                    <div class="gallery-buy-bg">
                        <div class="gallery-buy">
                            <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dlFeaturedProducts$ctl15$txtQuantity" type="text" value="1" maxlength="4" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_txtQuantity_15" class="textbox" style="width:25px;text-align:center" /><br />(quantity)
                        </div>
                        <div class="gallery-buy-button">
                            <div class="grey-button">
                                <a onclick="if(!isPositiveInteger(document.getElementById(&#39;ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_txtQuantity_15&#39;).value)){alert(&#39;Please enter a numeric value for the quantity&#39;);document.getElementById(&#39;ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_txtQuantity_15&#39;).select();document.getElementById(&#39;ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_txtQuantity_15&#39;).focus();return false;};" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_btnBuy_15" title="Add to Cart" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dlFeaturedProducts$ctl15$btnBuy&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">Add to Cart</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

</div>
        </span>
```

**Client HTML - Chrome**

```
<span valign="top">
                <div id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_pnlProduct_15" onkeypress="javascript:return WebForm_FireDefaultButton(event, &#39;ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_btnBuy_15&#39;)">

                    <div class="gallery-product">
                    <div class="gallery-in-stock">
                        <img id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_imgStock_15" src="../images/in-stock.png" alt="This item is in stock." />
                    </div>
                        <div class="gallery-product-image">
                            <a id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_hlProductImage_15" title="2m HDMI V1.4 Cable" href="Cables-(Ready-Made)/DVI-HDMI-Cables/Product-Specification-CB30202.aspx"><img src="http://www.globalpc.co.nz/prodimages/CB30201.jpg.axd?maxwidth=100&maxheight=100" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_imgProduct_15" alt="2m HDMI V1.4 Cable" border="0" /></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="gallery-product-details">
                            <div class="gallery-product-freight">

                            </div>
                            <div class="gallery-product-title">
                                <a id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_hlProductTitle_15" href="Cables-(Ready-Made)/DVI-HDMI-Cables/Product-Specification-CB30202.aspx">2m HDMI V1.4 Cable</a></strong>
                            </div>
                            <div class="gallery-product-price">
                                <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_lblProductPrice_15"></span> <span class="gallery-product-price-gst">Incl GST</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="gallery-product-usually">
                                <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_pnlUsually_15"><span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_lblWas_15"></span><span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_lblListPrice_15"></span></span>&nbsp;
                            </div>

                            <!--<div class="index-product-cash-back">
                                <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_divCashBack_15"><img src="images/cash-back-offer.png" alt="Get CASH back On This Item" title="Get CASH back On This Item" /></span>
                            </div>-->
                            <div class="gallery-product-blurb">
                                <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_lblWebBlurb_15"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dlFeaturedProducts$ctl15$ProductID" type="hidden" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_ProductID_15" value="CB30202" />
                        <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dlFeaturedProducts$ctl15$UniqueCode" type="hidden" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_UniqueCode_15" value="c9e963b7-4f99-4f1a-8165-28219fae0363" />
                        <div class="gallery-buy-bg">
                            <div class="gallery-buy">
                                <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dlFeaturedProducts$ctl15$txtQuantity" type="text" value="1" maxlength="4" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_txtQuantity_15" class="textbox" style="width:25px;text-align:center" /><br />(quantity)
                            </div>
                            <div class="gallery-buy-button">
                                <div class="grey-button">
                                    <a onclick="if(!isPositiveInteger(document.getElementById(&#39;ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_txtQuantity_15&#39;).value)){alert(&#39;Please enter a numeric value for the quantity&#39;);document.getElementById(&#39;ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_txtQuantity_15&#39;).select();document.getElementById(&#39;ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_txtQuantity_15&#39;).focus();return false;};" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_btnBuy_15" AlternateText="Add to Cart" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dlFeaturedProducts$ctl15$btnBuy&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">Add to Cart</a>
                                </div>
                                <input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dlFeaturedProducts$ctl15$btnHiddenBuy" value="" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_btnHiddenBuy_15" style="display:none;" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

</div>
            </span>
```

**HTML from Chrome v2**

```
<div id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_pnlProduct_1" onkeypress="javascript:return WebForm_FireDefaultButton(event, 'ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_btnBuy_1')">

                    <div class="gallery-product">
                    <div class="gallery-in-stock">
                        <img id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_imgStock_1" src="../images/in-stock.png" alt="This item is in stock.">
                    </div>
                        <div class="gallery-product-image">
                            <a id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_hlProductImage_1" title="2m HDMI V1.4 Cable" href="Cables-(Ready-Made)/DVI-HDMI-Cables/Product-Specification-CB30202.aspx"><img src="http://www.globalpc.co.nz/prodimages/CB30201.jpg.axd?maxwidth=100&amp;maxheight=100" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_imgProduct_1" alt="2m HDMI V1.4 Cable" border="0"></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="gallery-product-details">
                            <div class="gallery-product-freight">

                            </div>
                            <div class="gallery-product-title">
                                <a id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_hlProductTitle_1" href="Cables-(Ready-Made)/DVI-HDMI-Cables/Product-Specification-CB30202.aspx">2m HDMI V1.4 Cable</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="gallery-product-price">
                                <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_lblProductPrice_1"></span> <span class="gallery-product-price-gst">Incl GST</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="gallery-product-usually">
                                <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_pnlUsually_1"><span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_lblWas_1"></span><span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_lblListPrice_1"></span></span>&nbsp;
                            </div>

                            <!--<div class="index-product-cash-back">
                                <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_divCashBack_1"><img src="images/cash-back-offer.png" alt="Get CASH back On This Item" title="Get CASH back On This Item" /></span>
                            </div>-->
                            <div class="gallery-product-blurb">
                                <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_lblWebBlurb_1"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dlFeaturedProducts$ctl01$ProductID" type="hidden" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_ProductID_1" value="CB30202">
                        <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dlFeaturedProducts$ctl01$UniqueCode" type="hidden" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_UniqueCode_1" value="bdf06fb2-74fe-4848-b648-fce81e25c25c">
                        <div class="gallery-buy-bg">
                            <div class="gallery-buy">
                                <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dlFeaturedProducts$ctl01$txtQuantity" type="text" value="1" maxlength="4" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_txtQuantity_1" class="textbox" style="width:25px;text-align:center"><br>(quantity)
                            </div>
                            <div class="gallery-buy-button">
                                <div class="grey-button">
                                    <a onclick="if(!isPositiveInteger(document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_txtQuantity_1').value)){alert('Please enter a numeric value for the quantity');document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_txtQuantity_1').select();document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_txtQuantity_1').focus();return false;};" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_btnBuy_1" alternatetext="Add to Cart" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dlFeaturedProducts$ctl01$btnBuy','')">Add to Cart</a>
                                </div>
                                <input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dlFeaturedProducts$ctl01$btnHiddenBuy" value="" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_btnHiddenBuy_1" style="display:none;">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

</div>
```

**HTML from IE v2**

```
<span valign="top">
            <div id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_pnlProduct_15" onkeypress="javascript:return WebForm_FireDefaultButton(event, 'ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_btnBuy_15')">

                <div class="gallery-product">
                    <div class="gallery-product-image">
                        <a title="2m HDMI V1.4 Cable" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_hlProductImage_15" href="Computers/Cables-(Ready-Made)/DVI-HDMI-Cables/Product-Specification-CB30202.aspx"><img id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_imgProduct_15" alt="2m HDMI V1.4 Cable" src="http://www.globalpc.co.nz/prodimages/CB30201.jpg.axd?maxwidth=165&amp;maxheight=100" border="0"></a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="gallery-product-details">
                    <div class="gallery-product-freight">

                        </div>
                        <div class="gallery-product-title">
                            <a id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_hlProductTitle_15" href="Computers/Cables-(Ready-Made)/DVI-HDMI-Cables/Product-Specification-CB30202.aspx">2m HDMI V1.4 Cable</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="gallery-product-price">
                            <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_lblProductPrice_15">$19.00</span> <span class="gallery-product-price-gst">Incl GST</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="gallery-product-usually">
                            <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_pnlUsually_15"><span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_lblWas_15"></span><span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_lblListPrice_15"></span></span>&nbsp;
                        </div>

                          <div class="gallery-product-blurb">
                            <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_lblWebBlurb_15"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dlFeaturedProducts$ctl15$UniqueCode" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_UniqueCode_15" type="hidden" value="b2cb5ee5-97d4-44a7-99f7-ffa66790ae0c">
                    <div class="gallery-buy-bg">
                        <div class="gallery-buy">
                            <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dlFeaturedProducts$ctl15$txtQuantity" class="textbox" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_txtQuantity_15" style="width: 25px; text-align: center;" type="text" maxlength="4" value="1"><br>(quantity)
                        </div>
                        <div class="gallery-buy-button">
                            <div class="grey-button">
                                <a title="Add to Cart" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_btnBuy_15" onclick="if(!isPositiveInteger(document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_txtQuantity_15').value)){alert('Please enter a numeric value for the quantity');document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_txtQuantity_15').select();document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_txtQuantity_15').focus();return false;};" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dlFeaturedProducts$ctl15$btnBuy','')">Add to Cart</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

</div>
        </span>
```

**Edit**

The page in question is our landing page, and it displays a randomly ordered selection of about 30 products (from an SQL table generated by my boss some time ago).

Here are two products side by side:

[image]

This is what's confusing me, both products display almost all the same fields. Both have the instock tick, free delivery splotch, and an exta info label underneath. But on has a price and the other doesn't. Is this likely to be a server side problem? The items in question display correctly on every other page.

Comment: It is difficult to diagnose the problem without seeing the client-side HTML that is generated. Can you update your question with that code? I have a feeling it has something to do with how the controls are rendering the html.

Comment: Also, please check first that the HTML renders the same in both browsers. It is possible that somewhere in the background a control is giving different HTML based on the browser in use.

Comment: I've added the code.

Comment: How did you obtain the code you posted? Via "View Source" or using the developer tools to get the "live" version of the DOM that the browser is using? "View Source" is what the server sends, whereas the dev tools in both browsers show what is actually being used (which may be different, for example, if JS runs to change the DOM).

Comment: @GregL That is a very good point, and I will add that if there is an error in the HTML, browsers will sometimes try to correct it in the generated HTML, but they don't always get it right.

Comment: However, it is helpful to see both the generated source and source code from view source... For comparison...

Comment: @JoshuaDannemann Yeah, that was my thought. Particularly because I noticed an errant `</strong>` tag in the markup that may be causing the two browsers to try to fix the mismatched closing tag by placing an open tag somewhere that then breaks things. Particularly because the screenshots show that the title is bold in IE and not in Chrome.

Comment: @GregL: The first pair of Client codes were taken by using View Source, I've just added another pair from the dev tools. I think... I'm new at websites.

Comment: This is likely a CSS issue. You should add your related classes.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a guess, but I looked closely at the markup in your HTML, and there is a lone `</strong>` tag after your `hlProductTitle` hyperlink:

```
<div class="gallery-product-title">
    <a id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlFeaturedProducts_hlProductTitle_15" href="Computers/Cables-(Ready-Made)/DVI-HDMI-Cables/Product-Specification-CB30202.aspx">2m HDMI V1.4 Cable</a>
    </strong> <!-- <<<== HERE IT IS (I added the newline before it)
</div>
```

Because there is no matching opening `<strong>` tag, browsers will try to "fix" this by adding one for you, doing their best guess as to where it should go. Different browsers make different guesses, which could account for why you see a difference. Evidence to support my theory (and a clue for you for next time) is that in your screenshot from IE, the product title is bold, whereas in the Chrome screenshot it is not. Meaning, I believe, that IE is deciding to put the opening `<strong>` tag before the product heading, and Chrome is putting it goodness-knows-where.

Try adding the matching `<strong>` tag before the product title tag, and see if that resolves your issue.

Comment: I've edited the product title tag: `<strong><asp:HyperLink ID="hlProductTitle" runat="server"></asp:HyperLink></strong>` but it didn't seem to change anything. Thanks for pointing it out though.

Comment: @ChrisHinton Then you should compare the View Source view of the HTML in Chrome with the live view of the HTML from Devtools, and play "spot the difference". (The way I would do that is to make sure to use a "tidy" function like the one at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) on both bits of markup, and then paste the tidied result into some diff tool like [QuickDiff](http://www.quickdiff.com) to find any discrepancies).

Comment: @ChrisHinton The fact that you are not even getting the $19.00 price populated in the markup sent from the server for Chrome does point to something in your server side code that is causing different markup to be sent to Chrome than IE. Are you using any 3rd party components on the server side that modify what gets sent to the client? Or do you have any custom browser detection code?

Comment: I've made a quick edit to the question to show that it's a problem that doesn't affect every single product... but there doesn't seem to be any reason behind the products it's not working with?

Comment: Because it is a random selection of products each time you refresh, it might be that the data is actually not returned correctly from the server, so there is nothing to populate the label text with. Have you run the query that the server runs a bunch of times in SQL Server (or whatever you are using) to verify that the price is always returned correctly? It does appear to be a server side issue somewhere, because the data is not present in the HTML being sent from the server.

Comment: Through the dual efforts of me not changing anything and possible black magic... it works now. I didn't change anything. I'm confused, but relieved. Thanks for all the help.